# Axis2 Java2WSDL wrapping exceptions unecessarily

Tags: java, wsdl, apache-axis

I'm migrating a web service from Axis to Axis2 and running into an issue with the Java2WSDL not handling the method exceptions in an expected way.  I built a simple example service to show the issue:

```
package ws.hello;

public interface HelloService
{
    public String sayHello(String name) throws Exception;
}
```

Using the Java2WSDL in Axis I get a fairly straightforward WSDL.  I would continue using that WSDL but Axis2 will not generate a client from it - it throws an error that it can't parse the WSDL.

Using the Java2WSDL in Axis2 I get something much more complex.  Here's the interesting part:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:ns1="http://org.apache.axis2/xsd" xmlns:ns="http://hello.webservices" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" targetNamespace="http://hello.webservices">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://hello.webservices">
            <xs:element name="HelloServiceException">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="HelloServiceException" nillable="true" type="ns:Exception"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:complexType name="Exception">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Message" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
```

Specifically, the problem is the exception.  The thrown exception is tied to the namespace and seems to wrap the original exception complex type.  This destroys any backward compatibility for existing clients.

Is there something I'm missing in the various command-line arguments that will prevent this?